# Colors on iPhone display darker than color values

Tags: iphone

I recently noticed that colors are now displaying darker on iPhone than their actual color values. (Taking an iphone screenshot of an image and using a color utility show that the color values are darker). This seems to be a recent change as I have an iphone screenshot of the same image on OS 3.0. Has Apple changed the iPhone's gamma or is something else going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be one with Snow Leopard. When images are resized in Preview under Snow Leopard, the RGB spectrum is shifted towards red.

Answer (score -1):

IIRC the iPhone screenshot function saves JPEGs, which utilise lossy compression. The compression *might* be damaging the colour values.

If you're getting different results on different OS versions it might just be a different JPEG encoder or different configuration of it!

For best results, try taking a screenshot of large area of solid colour (32x32 pixels to be really sure, as JPEG sublocks often go to 16x16 pixels) and checking the colour value of that.

Comment: iPhone screenshots are saved as .png files.

Comment: Since when? I could have sworn the iTouch saved JPGs back when I did a bit of web programming for it a while ago.

Comment: http://www.ehow.com/how_4605966_screen-shot-iphone-screenshot-app.html seems to agree with me.

Comment: In that case this isn't the cause of the problem. I'll leave my answer here in case it helps someone else...